# Java service Using JarClassLoader

Tags: jar

My Java service loads a jar file using JarClassLoader and created instance using JclObjectFactory.

1.Once the service is up and once the jar is loaded, will the jar just loaded be cached by JVM

2.Will the continuous run of the service cause memory leak issues loading the same jar again and again.?

Please clarify.